# Who will review/accept Tag Wiki excerpts?

Tags: discussion

Just out of curiosity, would like to know who will review/accept tag wiki/excerpts edits and reputation required to review tag edits.

Comment: this isn't 100% related, but i think the only place to communicate with you directly is chat, and i don't really use that. please stop creating tags without 5 or more questions. we appreciate your efforts here immensely, but tags need to be warranted, hence the minimum of 5 to create the tag. i hope you understand, and i also did this until a mod corrected me. thanks!

Comment: it also seems like you are editing the same tags 2x in an attempt to game system/get points. please stop doing this as well. again, the enthusiasm and motivation are great; gaming the system...not so much. answer some questions! edit some questions/answers! its annoying to have to earn your way, i get it. but please stop doing this.

Comment: @albert Noted with Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That privilege is reached at [1500 reputation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (on non-beta sites, it's 5000):

> #### Finding tag wikis to vote on
>
> Users with the privilege to vote on tag wikis will start seeing them appear randomly between other posts in the [Suggested Edits review task](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits). You can also visit the tag wiki page itself and click on the edit links (similar to a regular post with a suggested edit pending on it) to view the suggestion and vote on it from there.

Tag definitions/creations are only necessary if they have five or more questions. The reason being that there are plenty of users/questions/topics that come here for one answer, and never come back. Creating a tag for one question has potential to create unnecessary bloat.

Comment: how come you don't help mod questions?

Comment: @albert thanks for the addition; I was just wondering if your comment was directed at me? I know a lot about Stack Exchange but not really about datasets ... I guess I could try the more programming related questions, as far as they are on-topic.

Comment: yes that comment was for you. sorry i didn't name you. i find it incredibly bizarre how SE has employees involved in meta. not the involvement, but how its gone down. i am unaware of any communication between employees and mods here. i could be wrong. feels like y'all just showed up and answer things as you see fit. without communicating at all with the mods. this question you answered, left out some key information. its frustrating, considering this is all volunteer time for us, and not for you.

Comment: my original comment was in frustration. i apologize. i just know i would greatly appreciate help on the real site vs. here. this space is very quiet, i'm not aware of any need for help here. clearly SE has an agenda, its their space, I get it. what i don't get is how its all gone down. furthermore, meta's seem to be places for users with in depth content knowledge. except for the SE members that show up and answer things as they see fit. i hope this doesn't feel like an attack, i'm just talking to you because you are here.

Comment: @albert I'm a volunteer, just like you. By the way, the user is *not* creating new tags, they're providing descriptions for them. Whether that's useful is another matter, different communities have different policies about tagging.